# Gparted error moving partition and shrinking it

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I used Gparted on live usb trying to enlarge my windows partition, I am trying to move the unallocated space out of the extended partition by shrinking and moving it but I keep getting an error

[image]

[image]

```
Libparted 3.2 Move /dev/sda3 to the right and shrink it from 98.92 GiB to 32.50 GiB 00:00:01 ( ERROR ) calibrate /dev/sda3 00:00:01 ( SUCCESS ) path: /dev/sda3 (partition) start: 63676414 end: 271120383 size: 207443970 (98.92 GiB) move partition to the right and shrink it from 98.92 GiB to 32.50 GiB 00:00:00 ( ERROR ) old start: 63676414 old end: 271120383 old size: 207443970 (98.92 GiB) requested start: 202969088 requested end: 271122431 requested size: 68153344 (32.50 GiB) libparted messages ( INFO ) Can't have overlapping partitions
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you changing alignment from Cylinder to MiB?

If so you might work around the issue by either:

- Use "Align to MiB" and try leaving at least 1 MiB unallocated space at the start or end of the partition when resizing.
- Use "Align to Cylinder" to maintain cylinder alignment when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

The pictures tell the tale. You are trying to shrink an extended partition without shrinking it's members. As there is a very limited amount of space available there, if I were you and faced with this dilemma I would try shrinking /dev/sda4 (where the lions share of your space is) and moving it to the right and then moving /dev/sda3 to the right (without resizing that one. this should free up space for you to expand /dev/sda2 which appears to be your goal.

Comment: that's what i did and that's where i got the unllocated 66gb from 
but /dev/sda3 causes an error everytime i try to move it